# NVDA/JAWS: Always read a page from the beginning (even on a re-visit)

Tags: nvda, jaws-screen-reader

NVDA sometimes seems to remember the position until where I have read a page. When I re-visit that same page, the cursor is placed at this position.

While this may seem handy sometimes, it can lead to unpredictable behaviour e.g. when in a shopping cart and removing the last item. When the page is reloaded, the focus is stuck somewhere in the footer, because the last item isn't there anymore.

I want to disable this, e.g. I always want to have the cursor placed to the beginning of the page (except when the focus is explicitly placed using JavaScript). But I don't find the option for it.

In JAWS, there's a similar option, but I don't remember how it was called (something like "Skip visited elements" maybe?)

I have created a working demo of the problem here:

http://developer-guide.access4all.ch/en/examples/remember_position_when_revisiting_page_example